# Can I calculate the new standard deviation when adding a value without knowing the original set of values?

Tags: standard-deviation

I have these three mathematical values that describe an unknown set of values.

- Mean (population mean, not from sample)

  $\bar{x} = 3$
- Standard deviation

  $s = 1.5$
- Number of elements in population (number of values in original set)

  $n = 15$

Now I have another value ($x = 4$) that adds to the unknown group of original values.

Is there a way to calculate the new standard deviation without knowing the original set of values?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can, but have you to take a small detour. Remember that the standard deviation is the square root of the variance, which is a lot easier to work with:
$$
s^2 = \frac{1}{N-1} \sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \bar{x}_N)^2
$$

Now suppose we have computed the variance $s_{N-1}^2$ and mean $\bar{x}_{N-1}$ based on N-1 samples, and a new sample $x_N$ arrives and you want to compute $s_N^2$. If you look at the difference in the sums of the squared differences used in the formulas for variance you get something surprisingly simple:

$$
(N-1)s_N^2 - (N-2)s_{N-1}^2 = (x_N-\bar{x}_N)(x_N - \bar{x}_{N-1}) \\
$$

(See [the full derivation](http://jonisalonen.com/2013/deriving-welfords-method-for-computing-variance/))

Therefore the updated variance is
$$
s_N^2 = \frac{(N-2)s_{N-1}^2 + (x_N-\bar{x}_N)(x_N - \bar{x}_{N-1})}{N-1}
$$

and the updated standard deviation would be just the square root. If you want the population variance or standard deviation replace N-1 with N and N-2 with N-1.

Comment: Awesome blog, thanks for sharing!