# what value can I add to the data set without changing the variance

Tags: statistics

what value can I add to the data set without changing the variance for example
$\begin{array}{c}
  X1 = [6&3&8&5&3]
    \end{array},Var(X1) = 4.5 \\$  .
what new value can I add so $\begin{array}{c}
  X2 = [6&3&8&5&3&a]
    \end{array}$ so that the $Var(X2) = 4.5 \\$
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, how about you calculate the variances of both of the sets (the latter will be a function of $a$) and then solve for $a$ ?

Comment: Just use the formula for variance on $X2$ and set it equal to $4.5$.

Comment: there is no more elegant way? no value that will depend on the STD etc?

Comment: There are two solutions, symmetric about the mean of $X_1$ as you might expect, and probably the result of solving a quadratic equeation.  The answer depends on whether you use the $\frac1{n-1}$ or $\frac{1}{n}$ definition of variance

Comment: I'm using $1/n-1$

Comment: You can use the formula given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/775678)

Comment: See as well this very thorough [answer]( https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/361801), in particular the paragraph : "behavior of moments under partitioning of data" : https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/361801